# Ошибка конструктора формы после успешного обновления проекта с DevExpress12.2 до 15.2

Tags: c#, update, devexpress

немного странная ситуация: после успешного обновления проекта VisualStudio с DevExpress12.2 до 15.2 *на этапе разработки* конструктор(дизайнер) формы "падает" с необработанным исключением;  Сведения:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "DevExpress.Data.v12.1, Version=12.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" либо одну из их зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл.
   в System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   в System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   в System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
   в System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
   в System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
   в System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, RuntimeType caType)
   в System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
   в System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(Assembly element, Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
   в System.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(Assembly element, Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
   в DevExpress.Xpf.CreateLayoutWizard.CreateLayoutWizardExtension.IsAssemblyConsistent(Assembly assembly)
   в DevExpress.Xpf.CreateLayoutWizard.CreateLayoutWizardExtension.IsAppDomainAssembliesConsistent()
   в DevExpress.Xpf.CreateLayoutWizard.CreateLayoutWizardExtension.UpdateAdornerMenus()
   в DevExpress.Xpf.CreateLayoutWizard.CreateLayoutWizardExtension.OnActiveViewChanged(Object sender, ViewChangedEventArgs e)
   в System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DocumentViewContext.OnActiveViewChanged(ViewChangedEventArgs e)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DocumentViewContext.SetActiveDocumentAndView(SceneView view, Item item, HostViewEventArgs e)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DocumentViewContext.SetActiveView(SceneView view, HostViewEventArgs e)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DocumentViewContext.CreateAndOpenViewInternal(SceneDocument document, CancellationToken cancelToken, Boolean activate, Boolean ensureOpenInHost)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner>b__0(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass6_0`1.<MarshalInWithCancellation>b__0()
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()

System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "DevExpress.Data.v12.1, Version=12.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" либо одну из их зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл.

Server stack trace: 
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalInSynchronous(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallModality callModality, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalIn(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, CallModality callModality, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalIn(IRemoteObject targetObject, Action action, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, CallModality callModality, ApartmentState apartmentState, String memberName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.MarshalInWithCancellation[TResult](IRemoteCancellationToken remoteToken, Func`2 func, ApartmentState apartmentState)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IRemoteHostProject remoteProject, IRemoteHostSourceItem remoteItem, IRemoteHostTextEditor remoteEditor, IRemoteCancellationToken remoteToken)
   в System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   в System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   в System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   в System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IRemoteHostProject remoteProject, IRemoteHostSourceItem remoteItem, IRemoteHostTextEditor remoteEditor, IRemoteCancellationToken cancelToken)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.CreateDesignerImpl(IRemoteDesignerService ds, IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, RemoteCancellationToken remoteCancelToken)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IDesignerService.CreateDesigner>b__0(IRemoteDesignerService ds, RemoteCancellationToken remoteToken)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass5_0`1.<MarshalOutWithCancellation>b__0(IRemoteDesignerService ds)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.<>c__DisplayClass29_0`1.<MarshalOut>b__0()
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()

System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "DevExpress.Data.v12.1, Version=12.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" либо одну из их зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл.
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOutSynchronous(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, WaitHandle timeoutSignal, CancellationToken cancelToken, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOut(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, WaitHandle timeoutSignal, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TValue](RemoteHandle`1 targetObject, Action action, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, ApartmentState apartmentState, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TValue](RemoteHandle`1 targetObject, Action`1 action, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, ApartmentState apartmentState, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.MarshalOutWithCancellation[TResult](CancellationToken cancelToken, Func`3 func, ApartmentState apartmentState)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
```

т.е. почему-то продолжает требовать DevExpress.Data.v12.1, НО всё компиллируется и запускается без ошибок, и такая проблема только в VS2015, а в VS2010 всё нормально. Причём, DE перед установкой вроде требует удалять старую версию. 
Гуглил Яндексом, не нашёл упоминаний о таком :( помогите побороть эту ерунду.

**UPD:** проверил ещё в VS2017community тоже всё компиллиться и конструктор(дизайнер) формы работает штатно.

Comment: Для начала откройте references в Solution Explorer и посмотрите, куда ведёт ссылка на библиотеку.

Comment: Очевидно, что вы где то пытаетесь грузить версию 12, которую удалили

Comment: @AK  всё выполнялось автообновлением и зсамой студии; посмотрел, DevExpress.Data.v15.2 ведёт на существующий файл; в references сейчас нет ссылок на что-то 'v12', поиском проверил.

Comment: @tym32167 мне вот тоже бы так показалось, НО такая проблема только при работе из VS2015, из VS2010 всё ок... и везде всё компилиться.

Comment: Студия скорее всего не при чем. Создайте новый проект, добавьте туда 15 версию, добавьте код для открытия формы, запустите его. Если запустится норм, то ищите проблему в вашем солюшене

Comment: Посмотрите ещё раздел runtime\assemblyBinding в app.config

Comment: @tym32167 у меня уже *запускается норм* :) и компилится всё везде успешно -- просто на этапе разработке конструктор формы выдаёт необработанное исключение именно в VS2015 и не даёт поработать.
Подскажите, куда в солюшн посмотреть?

Comment: Если конструктор формы выдает исключения в дизайн режиме, значит вы не до конца удалили предыдущий devexpress. Я бы заново все девекспессы удалил, писал бы им в поддержку, отключил все связанные с ним плагины, в окне Tools убрал бы все, что связано с dx, и если все это не поможет, то переставил бы студию, но это как последний вариант.

Comment: @AK  эмм, у меня в app.config вообще нет `runtime\assemblyBinding`, ни вместе, ни по отдельности, ни значений, ни разделов -- поиском проверял -- это что-то значит?

Comment: Не могу сказать за WPF, а в WinForms такое поведение обычно означает что где-то в папке bin завалялась какая-нибудь ненужная или не перекомпилировавшася сборка одного из ваших проектов, которая почему-то загрузилась в design surface и тянет за собой старые зависимости.

Answer (score 0):

всем спс, натолкнули на правильное решение, к счастью не потребовались радикальные меры.
Суть в том, что при обновлении проекта DevExpress естественно не удаляет старые версии своих *.DLL скопированные локально в `\bin\ release|debug` -- стоило только их все вручную убрать проблема исчезла.
*Предположительно*, причина такая:
изначально у некоторых *.DLL было снято свойство "копировать локально", но при этом они там были скопированы -- и при обновлении DevExpress проекта с v12.2 до v15.2 хоть ссылки были переставлены на новые *.DLL, но приоритет видимо остался за скопированными локально(старыми v12.2) рядом с исполняемым файлом приложения, которые требовали для работы отсутствующий `DevExpress.Data.v12.1`.